# How show tag of button?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview, uibutton

In below code i want display tag of each button on console. I tried for that but it show out of scope. How do that?

```
 - (void)loadView {
[super loadView];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
NSInteger numberOfViews = 33;
[btnMenu setTag:0 ];
for (int i = 1; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
    CGFloat yOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
    UIView *awesomeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    //awesomeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5/i green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1];
    btnMenu = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    //NSData *data =UIImageJPEGRepresentation(, 1);
    [btnMenu setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"page-%d.jpg",i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    CGRect frame = btnMenu.frame;
    frame.size.width=320;
    frame.size.height=460;
    frame.origin.x=0;
    frame.origin.y=0;
    btnMenu.frame=frame;
    [btnMenu setTag:i];
    btnMenu.alpha = 1;
    [btnMenu addTarget:self action:@selector(btnSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [awesomeView addSubview:btnMenu];

    [scroll addSubview:awesomeView];
    [awesomeView release];
}
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
[scroll release];
```

}

```
-(IBAction)btnSelected:(id)sender{
switch (btnMenu.tag) {
        NSLog(@"%d",btnMenu.tag);

}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
-(IBAction)btnSelected:(id)sender{
  UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
  int whichButton = button.tag;
  NSLog(@"Current TAG: %i", whichButton);
}
```

**EDIT:**

do you really need the method as an IBAction method?

cannot you use it as a void one?

```
-(void)btnSelected:(id)sender{
  UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
  int whichButton = button.tag;
  NSLog(@"Current TAG: %i", whichButton);
}
```

Comment: it give this error :- request for member 'tag' in something not a structure or union

Comment: can u tell me can i do this for image view. Can you see my this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786170/how-add-a-uibutton-on-every-image-of-image-view-which-is-in-scroll-view

Comment: you can just use an image directly in a UIButton, as you do in this post code, but you can also avoid to use a lot of UIView, one for every UIButton. why don't you just add the UIButtons directly to your scrool?     [scroll addSubview:btnMenu];

 and just delete all UIView (if you don't need for other reasons...)

Comment: if i want u use simple image view instead of button with image then how i implement all action?and how add scroll view on every image so that image can scroll in horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(IBAction)btnSelected:(id)sender{
    UIButton* btnMenu = (UIButton*)sender;
    switch (btnMenu.tag) {
    NSLog(@"%d",btnMenu.tag);

    }
}
```

Comment: Try UIView instead of UIButton may be you are setting same tag to two components

Answer (score 0):

try this code as your action method

```
-(IBAction)btnSelected:(id)sender{
switch (sender.tag) {
    NSLog(@"%d",sender.tag);
```

}}

this prints the tag of the current button that is selected .

TNQ

Comment: error: request for member 'tag' in something not a structure or union

Comment: if u want to just print the tag of the current button you can even remove the switch statement.place only the log statement in the action method

Answer (score 0):

While creating your button create it locally (inside for loop), otherwise it will contain only last tag.

```
totalNoOfImages=32;
```

as:

```
for(int i=0;i<totalNoOfImages;i++)
{   
    UIButton *button=[[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*50,0,45,44)] autorelease];       

    //SETTING TAG FOR IMAGE
    [button setTag:i];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(btnSelected:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [scrollView addSubview:iconImageSlide];
}
```

Following method will show the tag:

```
- (void) btnSelected:(id)sender
{
    int btnId=[(UIButton *)sender tag];
    NSLog(@"btnTag= %d", ibtnId)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)btnSelected:(id)sender{

UIButton *btnSelected = sender;

NSLog(@"%d",btnSelected.tag);
}
```

Above code is working for me and it is printing tag value in log. You must did something wrong.